# How to set org-tag-alist on a per capture template?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to have different fast tag selections
depending on the capture template used.

- Personal template - org-tag-alist = gym, family, friends, chores
- Work     template - org-tag-alist = mettings, docs, seminar

I run the org-set-tags-command at the end but the selection doesn't show up. The functions are being called cause I can see the org-tag-alist changed in describe-variable.

It's prompting me for tags `0 Tags [add more using TAB]` instead of the quick entry when I run `org-set-tags-command`. If I set org-tag-alist outside of the function it works but then I don't have different tags on a per template.

```lisp
(defvar org-capture-templates nil)

(defun my/work-tags ()
  "Set work tags."
  (interactive)
  (setq org-tag-alist '(("meetings" . ?m) ("docs" . ?d) ("seminar" . ?s)))
 (= 1 2) ; Need to return string or nil.
  )

(defun my/personal-tags ()
  "Set personal tags."
  (interactive)
  (setq org-tag-alist '(("gym" . ?g) ("family" . ?f) ("friends" . ?F)("chores" . ?c)))
 (= 1 2) ; Need to return string or nil.
  )

(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
                 '("W"          ; key
                   "Work"    ; name
                   entry        ; type
                   (file (lambda () (concat user-emacs-directory "todos.org" ))) ; target
                   "* %(my/work-tags) %^{Task}%^{DESCRIPTION}p" :prepend t))

(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
                 '("P"          ; key
                   "Personal"    ; name
                   entry        ; type
                   (file (lambda () (concat user-emacs-directory "todos.org" ))) ; target
                   "* %(my/personal-tags) %^{Task}%^{DESCRIPTION}p" :prepend t))
```

I use vanilla emacs, but tried it on doom to make sure it wasn't my configuration.

Comment: First thing: you have the same accelerator key, "f", assigned to two tags, "fmaily" and "friends", within your personal set.

Comment: Next thing: why do you want to go to the trouble of doing this? The built-in facilities already provide what you are looking for, I think. You will need to read the manual starting at the section on "Setting Tags" and its following section on tag hierarchies. `(info "(org) Setting Tags")`.

Comment: @PhilHudson Thanks for pointing that out. I still get the same outcome when I change it to an "F". Without different org-tag-alist how would I use the same keys ? "c" for "config" in Emacs category would conflict with "c" for "chores" in Personal. I would have to use different names or capital letters.